# Referencing one field of a composite key and 'ON DELETE CASCADE' only if no references

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, composite-primary-key, cascading-deletes

I'm working on a mysql database and I'd like to reference a part of a composite key (with 2 fields in it) and avoid mysql to delete the referencing entry when the referenced entry is delete if there is stilt a part of the composite key in the referenced table.

Here is the problem :

- Two tables :

  > - T1(**Some_PK**, #Pointer_To_PKA, some_field)
  > - T2(**PKA**, **PKB**, Some_field)
- T2 has a composite key made by two fields **PKA** and **PKB**
- In T1 there is a foreign key constraint which references T2's field **PKA** but not **PKB** (only half of the composite key is referenced).

The problem is that when I delete a row in T2, the 'ON CASCADE DELETE' constraint delete the row in T1 which references the one deleted in T2 but that row (from T1) also referenced other fields from T2 before its deletion :

```
============= T2 =============
 [PKA] | [PKB] |  Some_field
------------------------------
     1 |     1 | Some content
     1 |     2 |     abcdefgh
     2 |     3 |       zefhds
______________________________

==================== T1 ========================
 [Some_PK] |  #Pointer_To_PKA |    Some_field
------------------------------------------------
         A |                1 |   Lorem ipsum
         B |                2 | other content
         C |                1 |    dhtshfgnfn
________________________________________________
```

Using the example above, I'd like that when I remove the first row from T2 (**1**, **1**, 'Some content'), the first and the third row from T1 stay because there will still be an entry in T2 (the 2nd row) which contains the half of the composite key referenced by T1.

Does someone know how to deal with this?

Comment: This won't work. You'll have to use a compound foreign key to keep the data consistent. Or create ON DELETE trigger for T2, that will check the necessary conditions without using foreign keys (bad idea).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer.
I solved the problem using a "fake" row in T2 : I created a static entry (temp) in T2 which is temporary, I assigned temp to #Pointer_To_PKA, I deleted the row in T2 and re-assigned the previous key to T1.
I'm not sure this is the best thing to do but I had to keep this "half-referencing" in T1 because of the database architecture.

Answer (score 0):

I almost never say, "Don't do that."

But [don't do that](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

> . . . the system does not enforce a requirement that the referenced
>   columns be UNIQUE or be declared NOT NULL. The handling of foreign key
>   references to nonunique keys or keys that contain NULL values is not
>   well defined for operations such as UPDATE or DELETE CASCADE. You are
>   advised to use foreign keys that reference only UNIQUE (including
>   PRIMARY) and NOT NULL keys.

You don't have a unique constraint on PKA. So follow the advice in the documentation. Redesign your tables.